# Buscar elemento da tabela intermediária utilizando o Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

eu estou desenvolvendo um sistema que tenho uma situação de um relacionamento N:N e preciso criar uma terceira tabela.
A relação é entre **Produto** e **Cor**. dentro do Model de Produto, coloquei essa função:

```
public function colors()
{
 return $this->belongsToMany('App\Color', 'product_colors', 'product_id', 'color_id')
 ->withPivot('price', 'id');
}
```

Agora precisava acessar um elemento do meio da tabela sem precisar dar um foreach. Como devo fazer essa consulta?

Comment: será que é isto que procuras ? `$product->colors()->findOrFail(1, ['product_color_id']);`

Comment: foreach ($product->colors() as $color) {
    echo $color->pivot->price;
}

Comment: Eu queria não precisar usar o foreach Jorge Costa.

Comment: O findOrFail não vai functionar pq ele não vai buscar da tabela intermediaria, mas sim da tabela que está vinculada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na hora de fazer uma consulta você pode usar relacionamento da seguinte forma:

```
Model::with('colors')->get();
```

O with puxa a função que você criou no Model que você usou belongsToMany, caso saiba pra que serve o get() é pra puxar todos os dados, mas caso queira fazer um where no relacionamento segue o código:

```
Model::with('colors')->whereHas('colors', function($query) use ($nome){
   $query->where('nome', $nome);
})->first();
```

No exemplo acima pedi o primeiro registro, espero que tenha entendido.